# HealthKit requestAuthorization for correlationType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressure)

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, healthkit

I am trying to read bloodPressure data from HealthKit and I wonder why I have to ask for `.bloodPressureSystolic` and `.bloodPressureDiastolic` instead of `.bloodPressure`

What I am trying to do is asking

```
requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: dataTypesToRead, completion: { ... })
```

where `dataTypesToRead = HKObjectType.correlationType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressure)` (ps: this is just for simplicity, `correlationType(forIdentifier: )` should be unwrapped)

and the app crashes. So I am guessing that one cannot `requestAuthorization` for `correlationType(forIdentifier: )`

if I use `HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier:)` or `.categoryType(forIdentifier:)` then `requestAuthorization` works perfectly, also with `.bloodPressureSystolic` and `.bloodPressureDiastolic`

If my guess is correct then why Apple says:

**typesToRead
A set containing the data types you want to read. This set can contain any concrete subclass of the `HKObjectType` class (any of the `HKCharacteristicType , HKQuantityType, HKCategoryType, HKWorkoutType or HKCorrelationType classes`). If the user grants permission, your app can read these data types from the HealthKit store.**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614152-requestauthorization

is my guess correct? why I can't ask permission for `HKObjectType.correlationType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressure)` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HealthKit doesn't require authorization for correlation types because your app can only query for correlations with member objects that it is authorized to read. It seems like the documentation is just a little misleading when it mentions `HKCorrelationType` classes.